# Does calling `setData` in `useMutation` affect subsequent calls to `useQuery`'s internal authentication checks?

Tags: trpc

Does calling `setData` make the following calls of the respective `useQuery` ignore the internal authentication checks?

Say I have a getUserList query like this:

```
  getList: publicProcedure
    .input(z.object({ listId: z.number() }))
    .query(async ({ ctx, input }) => {
      const list = await ctx.prisma.list.findUnique({
        where: {
          id: input.listId,
        },
      });
      if (!!list && !list.public && list.userId !== ctx.session?.user.id) {
        throw new TRPCError({
          code: 'UNAUTHORIZED',
          message: 'You are not authorized to make this request',
        });
      }
      return {
        list,
      };
    }),
```

Now, in a mutation's `onMutate`, I call `getList.setData(...)` to perform an optimistic update.
Is there a risk for the subsequent call to `getList.useQuery()` to be called by a non-authorized user?

Even if the mutation itself (e.g. `addToList`) has authorization checks, `onMutate` actually runs before the mutation itself, so I can imagine a scenario where `setData` leaks data to unauthorized users?